# Appium cannot find element inside GridView on the android emulator

Tags: android, appium

Either Appium Inspector or tests run by Appium cannot find element placed inside GridView. It concerns just Android and just emulator. On Android device it works fine.

Using uiautomatorviewer tool can localise that element and give me some details about it, my element is there.

Below you can see two ways I try to find that element. Both works on the device, however none works on the emulator.

First:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated( By.xpath("//android.view.View[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.GridView[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]")));

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.GridView[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]"));
```

Second:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("tile1")));    
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("tile1"));
```

When I look just for GridView Appium finds it, but without any content.

Inside my GridView I have tiles with icon and title.

Any Ideas?